# Use operator LIKE in query set in Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

i have the next code

```
if(isset($_GET['f_search'])){
    $s_str = trim($_GET['f_search']);
    if(strlen($s_str) >= 3){
        $query->set('s', $s_str );
    }
}
```

This already work for search exact word, but if i want search example: 'Soccer' or 'Soccer-fine', i get different results, i want use operator LIKE for give me similar results but i dont know how use it, maybe

```
$query->set('s', 'LIKE', $s_str );
```

or something like that.

I use this in pre_get_posts of the archive page.

Thanks for the help, regards.

Comment: Not familiar with wordpress but maybe you need to append the wildcard on the string. `$s_str . '%'`

Comment: Not work i tried this and nothing

$query->set('s', $s_str . '%' );
$query->set('s', LIKE, $s_str . '%' );
$query->set('s', '%' . $s_str . '%' );

Comment: `$query` is what and `set` is what? That `s` looks like `mysqli` syntax for a prepared statement.

Comment: ? - https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/279353/using-pre-get-posts-for-meta-value-of-like-comparison-on-acf-repeater-sub-field

Comment: Nop nothing work, i already try 

$query->set('s', [
                    'meta_key' => 'post_title',
                    'meta_value' => '%'.$s_str.'%',
                    'compare' => 'LIKE'
                ]
            );

maybe i need think how make the search other way, i will ask in wordpress foro, $query and set and 's' are from wordpress syntax

Comment: @user3783243 `$query` is the global variable for the WordPress query and `set` allows you to alter the main query with arguments. The `s` is the query string variable from the search.

Comment: @AlanCordova there's not really a good way to do what you want in the native query - without a ton of other work. Look into Relevannsi Search plugin. That replaces the default WP search with something much more powerful - including LIKE results: https://wordpress.org/plugins/relevanssi/

Comment: I need to make for this way, because i already have a complex query filters and many other things for that query, so change the way that work in this point is imposible, not matter if not is a good way, i prefer hard code than to use a plugin, just for this situation.

Comment: Thanks for the help, i search for some fast solution, but in a few days i will migrate for worpress to laravel so not is really important anymore